# Error run react-scripts start: event.js 182

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-scripts

I cloned a project in bitbucket, and when I run npm start, I received an error:

```
 events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/public ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1371:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1397:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/eoffice-chat-web/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eoffice-chat-web@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eoffice-chat-web@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tom/.npm/_logs/2017-06-06T09_07_59_232Z-debug.log
```

Please help me fix it! Thank you.

Comment: It'll be easy to debug, if you could share the code

Answer (score 3):

The `ENOSPC` part of your error means that there is no space on the drive where it is running. Check to make sure you have enough space free on that partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed it.

Comment: That did not make it for me. I have plenty of disk space.

Answer (score -3):

**error execution events.js:182 on npm start**

The problem here is Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
You already have a process connected to port 3000, so do you have another node.js service running?

Comment: in general, this is usually the cause for this issue but specifically in this case, tim's answer is the relevant one due to the error he received.